# Две вьюшки для RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

У меня проблема в том, что нужно создать лист в котором 2 вьюшки, то есть первый Итем как Header идет, а второй динамически увеличивается. Сперва думал первый сделать как обычный блок а второй в `RecyclerView`, но почему-то мне показалось это неправильным. Так вот решил сделать на `RecyclerView` и в инете покапался и нашел один метод. Но почему то пустой экран.

Сперва что мне нужно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У них один и тот же модель тоесть,

```
public class TicketObjects {

private String departCity;
private String departAirport;
private String arriveCity;
private String arriveAirport;

private String departCode;
private String departTime;
private String departDate;
private String arriveCode;
private String arriveTime;
private String arriveDate;
private String transferCity;
private String flyDuration;
private String ticketPrice;
private int airlineLogo;
private String flight;

public TicketObjects(String departCity, String departAirport, String arriveCity, String arriveAirport,
                     String departCode, String departTime, String departDate,
                     String arriveCode, String arriveTime, String arriveDate,
                     String transferCity, String flyDuration, String ticketPrice, int airlineLogo, String flight) {


    this.departCity = departCity;
    this.departAirport = departAirport;
    this.arriveCity = arriveCity;
    this.arriveAirport = arriveAirport;

    this.departCode = departCode;
    this.departTime = departTime;
    this.departDate = departDate;
    this.arriveCode = arriveCode;
    this.arriveTime = arriveTime;
    this.arriveDate = arriveDate;
    this.transferCity = transferCity;
    this.flyDuration = flyDuration.trim().replaceFirst("^[0]{1}", "").replace(":", " h ") + " m";
    this.ticketPrice = ticketPrice;
    this.airlineLogo = airlineLogo;
    this.flight = flight;
}
```

**и так далее...
Вот мой адаптер:**

```
package kz.ticketdetail;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class DetailsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{
private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;

List<TicketObjects> ticketItems;
List<TicketObjects> ticketsHeader;
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
Context context;

public DetailsAdapter(Context context, List<TicketObjects> ticketItems, List<TicketObjects> ticketsHeader){
    this.context = context;
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.ticketItems = ticketItems;
    this.ticketsHeader = ticketsHeader;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    if(viewType == TYPE_HEADER)
    {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.ticket_details_header_item, parent, false);
        return  new DetailsHeader(v);
    }
    else if(viewType == TYPE_ITEM)
    {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.ticket_details_item, parent, false);
        return new DetailsItem(v);
    }
    return null;
}

private TicketObjects getItem(int position)
{
    return ticketItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int i) {


    if(holder instanceof DetailsHeader)
    {
        TicketObjects currentItem = getItem(i);
        DetailsHeader headerItem = (DetailsHeader)holder;

headerItem.detTotalDuration.setText(currentItem.getFlyDuration());
        headerItem.detDepartTime.setText(currentItem.getDepartTime());
        headerItem.detDepartDate.setText(currentItem.getDepartDate());
        headerItem.detArriveTime.setText(currentItem.getArriveTime());
        headerItem.detArriveDate.setText(currentItem.getArriveDate());
        headerItem.depDepartCity.setText(currentItem.getDepartCity());
        headerItem.detDepartAirport.setText(currentItem.getDepartAirport());
        headerItem.detArriveCity.setText(currentItem.getArriveCity());
        headerItem.detArriveAirport.setText(currentItem.getArriveAirport());

        headerItem.detFlight.setText(currentItem.getFlight());
        headerItem.airlineLogo.setImageResource(currentItem.getAirlineLogo());


    }

    if(holder instanceof DetailsItem)
    {
        TicketObjects currentItem = getItem(i);
        DetailsItem detailsItem = (DetailsItem)holder;
        detailsItem.detTotalDuration.setText(currentItem.getFlyDuration());
        detailsItem.detDepartTime.setText(currentItem.getDepartTime());
        detailsItem.detDepartDate.setText(currentItem.getDepartDate());
        detailsItem.detArriveTime.setText(currentItem.getArriveTime());
        detailsItem.detArriveDate.setText(currentItem.getArriveDate());
        detailsItem.depDepartCity.setText(currentItem.getDepartCity());
        detailsItem.detDepartAirport.setText(currentItem.getDepartAirport());
        detailsItem.detArriveCity.setText(currentItem.getArriveCity());
          detailsItem.detArriveAirport.setText(currentItem.getArriveAirport());

        detailsItem.detFlight.setText(currentItem.getFlight());
        detailsItem.airlineLogo.setImageResource(currentItem.getAirlineLogo());
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if(isPositionHeader(position))
        return TYPE_HEADER;
    return TYPE_ITEM;
}

private boolean isPositionHeader(int position)
{
    return position == 0;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return ticketItems.size();
}

class DetailsHeader extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView detTitleArriveCity;
    TextView detTitleDepartCity;
    TextView detTotalDuration;

    TextView detDepartTime;
    TextView detDepartDate;
    TextView detArriveTime;
    TextView detArriveDate;
    TextView depDepartCity;
    TextView detDepartAirport;
    TextView detArriveCity;
    TextView detArriveAirport;
    TextView detFlight;

    ImageView airlineLogo;

    public DetailsHeader(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        this.detTitleDepartCity = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.detTitleDepartCity);
        this.detTitleArriveCity = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.detTitleArriveCity);
        this.detTotalDuration = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.detTotalDuration);

        this.detDepartTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.detDepartTime);
        this.detDepartDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.detDepartDate);
        this.detArriveTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.detArriveTime);
        this.detArriveDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.detArriveDate);
        this.depDepartCity = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.depDepartCity);
        this.detDepartAirport = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.detDepartAirport);
        this.detArriveCity = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.detArriveCity);
        this.detArriveAirport = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.detArriveAirport);
        this.detFlight = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.detFlight);

        this.airlineLogo = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.detAirportLogo);
    }
}

class DetailsItem extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView transferCity;
    TextView detTotalDuration;

    TextView detDepartTime;
    TextView detDepartDate;
    TextView detArriveTime;
    TextView detArriveDate;
    TextView depDepartCity;
    TextView detDepartAirport;
    TextView detArriveCity;
    TextView detArriveAirport;
    TextView detFlight;

    ImageView airlineLogo;

    public DetailsItem(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        this.transferCity = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTransferCity);
        this.detTotalDuration = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.detTotalDuration);

        this.detDepartTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.detDepartTime);
        this.detDepartDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.detDepartDate);
        this.detArriveTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.detArriveTime);
        this.detArriveDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.detArriveDate);
        this.depDepartCity = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.depDepartCity);
        this.detDepartAirport = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.detDepartAirport);
        this.detArriveCity = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.detArriveCity);
        this.detArriveAirport = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.detArriveAirport);
        this.detFlight = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.detFlight);

        this.airlineLogo = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.detAirportLogo);
    }
  }
}
```

**Мой главный Активити:**

```
RecyclerView transferRecycler;

private List<TicketObjects> transferList;
private DetailsAdapter detailsAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ticket_details);

    transferRecycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.transferRecycler);
    transferRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    DetailsAdapter adapter = new DetailsAdapter(getApplicationContext(), getHeaderItem(), getDetailItem());
    transferRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public ArrayList<TicketObjects> getHeaderItem()
{

    ArrayList<TicketObjects> headeritem = new ArrayList<>();
    headeritem.add(new TicketObjects("Москва", "Шереметьево", "Нью-йорк", "Джон кеннеди", "SFO","13:45","16.09.2015","JKD","13:45","16.09.2015","Анкара", "1ч 15мин","15000", R.drawable.logo_flyduba, "Рейс: 543"));

    return headeritem;
}

public  List<TicketObjects> getDetailItem()
{
    ArrayList<TicketObjects> listItems = new ArrayList<>();

//данные просто пример

    listItems.add(new TicketObjects("Москва", "Шереметьево", "Нью-йорк", "Джон кеннеди", "SFO","13:45","16.09.2015","JKD","13:45","16.09.2015","Almaty", "1ч 15мин","15000", R.drawable.logo_flyduba, "Рейс: 543"));
    listItems.add(new TicketObjects("Москва", "Шереметьево", "Нью-йорк", "Джон кеннеди", "SFO","13:45","16.09.2015","JKD","13:45","16.09.2015","Almaty", "1ч 15мин","15000", R.drawable.logo_flyduba, "Рейс: 543"));
    listItems.add(new TicketObjects("Москва", "Шереметьево", "Нью-йорк", "Джон кеннеди", "SFO","13:45","16.09.2015","JKD","13:45","16.09.2015","Almaty", "1ч 15мин","15000", R.drawable.logo_flyduba, "Рейс: 543"));

    return listItems;
}
```

У меня просто белый экран, никаких ошибок. Да и мне кажется я просто все неправильно делаю. Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать такой список?

Comment: а как вы задаете int viewType?

Comment: @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        if(viewType == TYPE_HEADER)
        {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.ticket_details_header_item, parent, false);
            return  new DetailsHeader(v);
        }
        else if(viewType == TYPE_ITEM)
        {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.ticket_details_item, parent, false);
            return new DetailsItem(v);
        }
        return null;
    }

Comment: Вы проверьте под дебагом везде ли у вас заходит в Ваши условия

Comment: Ничего не нашел(

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка у Вас кроется в том, что первым у вас идет хидер, но getItem() берет данные из `ticketItems`, и в последствии вся логика проваливается. но даже замена списка данных не исправит ситуацию.

Вам как минимум нужно дописать логику адаптера, Пример который вы нашли, показывает, как установить хидер только для первой записи и только.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if(isPositionHeader(position))
        return TYPE_HEADER;
    return TYPE_ITEM;
}

private boolean isPositionHeader(int position)
{
    return position == 0; // хидер только для первой записи.
}
```

Кроме того у Вас 2 списка `List<TicketObjects>` а это значит у вас будет проблемы с `position`.

Как минимум вам нужно для начала объединить все `List<TicketObjects>` в один общий лист. Добавьте `переменную` в `TicketObjects` которая различает тип вьюхи (хидер\лайоут) и напишите логику для выдергивания

```
   @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return getItem(position).getYouTypeView(); // нечто подобное для простоты пусть вернет 0 хидер и 1 айтем
        }
```

Ну и соответственно подставляйте вью

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    if(viewType == TYPE_HEADER)
    {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.ticket_details_header_item, parent, false);
        return  new DetailsHeader(v);
    }
    else if(viewType == TYPE_ITEM)
    {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.ticket_details_item, parent, false);
        return new DetailsItem(v);
    }
    return null;
}
```

**UPD**
Добавьте в `TicketObjects`

```
public class TicketObjects {
..........
private int ticketViewType;


public TicketObjects(int ticketViewType.......) {
this.ticketViewType = ticketViewType;
}

public int getTicketViewType(){
return ticketViewType;
}
```

Обновите получение Списка до

```
public  List<TicketObjects> getDetailItem()
{
    ArrayList<TicketObjects> listItems = new ArrayList<>();

//данные просто пример

    listItems.add(new TicketObjects(DetailsAdapter.TYPE_HEADER, "Москва", "Шереметьево", "Нью-йорк", "Джон кеннеди", "SFO","13:45","16.09.2015","JKD","13:45","16.09.2015","Анкара", "1ч 15мин","15000", R.drawable.logo_flyduba, "Рейс: 543"));

    listItems.add(new TicketObjects(DetailsAdapter.TYPE_ITEM, "Москва", "Шереметьево", "Нью-йорк", "Джон кеннеди", "SFO","13:45","16.09.2015","JKD","13:45","16.09.2015","Almaty", "1ч 15мин","15000", R.drawable.logo_flyduba, "Рейс: 543"));
    listItems.add(new TicketObjects(DetailsAdapter.TYPE_ITEM, "Москва", "Шереметьево", "Нью-йорк", "Джон кеннеди", "SFO","13:45","16.09.2015","JKD","13:45","16.09.2015","Almaty", "1ч 15мин","15000", R.drawable.logo_flyduba, "Рейс: 543"));
    listItems.add(new TicketObjects(DetailsAdapter.TYPE_ITEM, "Москва", "Шереметьево", "Нью-йорк", "Джон кеннеди", "SFO","13:45","16.09.2015","JKD","13:45","16.09.2015","Almaty", "1ч 15мин","15000", R.drawable.logo_flyduba, "Рейс: 543"));

    return listItems;
}
```

Измените конструктор `DetailsAdapter`

```
public DetailsAdapter(Context context, List<TicketObjects> ticketItems){
    this.context = context;
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.ticketItems = ticketItems;
}
```

И тип доступа констант с private на public

```
public class DetailsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{
public static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
public static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1; ..........
```

ну и последнее

```
@Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return getItem(position).getTicketViewType(); // нечто подобное для простоты пусть вернет 0 хидер и 1 айтем
        }
```

Ответ исчерпывающий.

**UPD 2**

Посмотрел внимательно то что вам нужно и понял, что вам header **вообще** не нужен. достаточно одного `xml` файла

Comment: Не понял если честно про ENUM и объединение List. Пожалуйста подскажите мне туториалы по моей проблеме, Я стажер просто щас у меня в голове каша а результат должен показать через 2-3 часа. А на изучение всех этих не хватет времени... Надеюсь правильно поймете...

Comment: я обновил ответ ()

Comment: Объедините входные данные List<TicketObjects> ticketItems;
List<TicketObjects> ticketsHeader; - должен быть одним списком, последовательным. В TicketObjects добавьте переменную инт, которая будет хранить 0 хидер или 1 айтем.

Comment: TicketObject он и в других файлах будет использоваться. Но тогда нужно будет и в других файла его заполнять?

Comment: Обновил ответ, с вас причитается пиво ;) за рашение ТЗ)

Comment: Спасибо огромное но у меня первая разметка тоже скролится, то есть он должен бы только один раз на верху как хидер быть и вторая разметка только должна появляться... Блин, мне ппц как неприятно, но прошу о помощи(

Comment: https://github.com/TonicArtos/SuperSLiM используйте вот эту библиотеку, всю задачу за вас решить я не могу. Старайтесь.

Comment: https://github.com/timehop/sticky-headers-recyclerview вот еще для работы с хидерами